# Access to BIM-360 team projects/items,... with 2-legged authentication context

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to access to the hubs, projects and items in my BIM360 or A360 with 2-legged authentication context and don't want to direct the user to forge authentication page. What should I do in this case? How can I provide x-user-id in 2-legged authentication context?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, those are 3-legged API's only. You could *manually* log in your account once and obtain a 3-legged token that you store on the server and use to perform 3-legged requests to those endpoints. You would also need to implement some logic that will automatically refresh the token to keep it valid because if it expires you need to log in again. This is however not a common/recommended thing to do.

This article might be useful: [Landing your Forge OAuth authentication workflow](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/landing-your-forge-oauth-authentication-workflow.html)

Comment: But I need to an API that I can pass username/password/scopes and return token/refresh-token to me.

Comment: On the other hand in (GET Hubs) reference page [https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/] 
author said for Authorization, we must be use token where is obtained via either a two-legged or three-legged OAuth flow. And 
for two-legged authentication context, said that we can use x-user-id in request header. Please clarify about it or manually log in.